# TypeError: object of type 'function' has no len() while using BeautifulSoup and FancyURLopener

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I'm getting a weird error/traceback while trying to use BeautifulSoup. If you recall, in my previous questions, I was having trouble with BioPython. While those troubles are more or less on the verge of being solved, I have a new problem. The references that are scraped from PMC are not always pertinent to the plant-disease pair. For example, the plant or the disease may occur in the references, rather than the body of the fulltext, rendering that result a false positive. To get around this problem, one of the other interns working with us suggested that I use BeautifulSoup to parse the HTML from the PMC pages, and check if either of the plant/the disease occurs after the text 'References'. While trying to do this I got the 403 Forbidden error, and inferred from other answers on StackOverflow and GitHub that NCBI was somehow blocking urllib. To get around this problem, the suggested solution was to use Mozilla's FancyURLopener as an intermediary. However, I keep getting this weird traceback, and I can't, for the life of me, figure out what's wrong with the code. Here's the traceback:

```
scraperscript_python.py:54: DeprecationWarning: AppURLopener style of invoking requests is deprecated. Use newer urlopen functions/methods
  opener = AppURLopener()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraperscript_python.py", line 58, in <module>
    pmc_refsoup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 275, in __init__
    elif len(markup) <= 256 and (
TypeError: object of type 'function' has no len()
```

Here are the lines leading up to and including line 58:

```
# First print statement
  for plant, disease in plant_disease_list:
    search_query = generate_search_query(plant, disease)
    handle1 = Entrez.esearch(db="pmc", term=search_query, retmax="10")
    record1 = Entrez.read(handle1)
    pubmed_ids = record1.get("IdList")
    if len(pubmed_ids)==0:
      print("{}, {}, None".format(plant, disease))
  # Else statement, initializing BeautifulSoup for parsing fulltext to avoid false positives
    else:
      for pubmed_id in pubmed_ids:
        handle2 = Entrez.esummary(db="pmc", id=pubmed_id)
        records = Entrez.read(handle2)
        pmc_main = pubmed_id
        pmcid_string = str("http://ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC")
        append_pmcid = ("").join((pmcid_string + pmc_main))
        my_url = append_pmcid
        class AppURLopener(urllib.request.FancyURLopener):
          version = "Mozilla/5.0"
        opener = AppURLopener()
        uClient_response = opener.open(my_url)
        page_html = uClient_response.read
        uClient_response.close()
        pmc_refsoup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
```

I feel like there's something obvious I'm missing, but I can't figure it out, and it's driving me bananas.

Comment: Did you mean to write ˋpage_html = uClient_response.read()ˋ perhaps? Note the parentheses to actually call the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line

```
page_html = uClient_response.read
```

you are missing the brackets to call the `read` method, which means that you assign the method itself to `page_html` and later pass this to `soup` as a parameter, leading to the `TypeError`.

The correct way to call `read` is:

```
page_html = uClient_response.read()
```